# What's the meaning of 'pay' 'depay' in gstreamer world?

Tags: gstreamer, pipeline

I know some concepts in gstreamer like source, sink, pipeline, and pads.

Those are programming concepts and also literal English words, their meanings are related.

But I don't know the meaning of `pay` or `depay` like rtph264depay.

From some `gst_parse_launch` sample commands, it seems that rtph264depay is to receive the data of source.

So how to understand the word of `depay`? Pay as in pay some money so depay is like receive money?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is actually written in the category they are in:

```sh
$ gst-inspect-1.0 rtph264depay | grep Klass
  Klass                    Codec/Depayloader/Network/RTP
```

So it is short for `Payloader` and `Depayloader`. Similar to an `Muxer` and `Demuxer` or `Encoder` and `Decoder` but nothing here is really encoded/decoded or muxed/demuxed. Just existing data is packaged in a specific format. Sometimes I have seen people calling that `Packetizer` and `Depacketizer` as well.

Comment: Could you please provide some helpful links for more explanations? I'm also new  and interested in this field.